# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: won't return any string

Tags: iphone

I'm up to write a code for extract certain part of webpage, so I decide to use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: to parse HTML.
below is my test code

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"<html><body><div id='hi'><font size=20>hello world</font></div></body></html>" baseURL:nil];

NSString *hiValue = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.getElementById('hi')"];  

NSLog(@"value: %@",hiValue);
```

NSLog does not returning any strings on console. Does anyone give me some little help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're executing this code before the webpage has finished loading.

Try calling your code in the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method using [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951).

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [webView loadHTMLString:@"<html><body><div id='hi'><font size=20>hello world</font></div></body></html>" baseURL:nil];

    NSString *hiValue = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.getElementById('hi')"];  

    NSLog(@"value: %@",hiValue);
}
```

Don't forget to set the delegate in `viewDidLoad:`:

```
webView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsById returns an object not a String. You should use like this:

```
document.body.getElementById('hi').outerHTML
```